# Trying to accumulate and sort random numbers into bins

Tags: c, arrays, random

I've create a list of random values in C, using the code below.

I need to sort these values into 200 bins distributed over the interval from 0 to 4, then write information about the bins to a file, though right now I'm only concerned with the former.

How can I write a loop that dynamically creates bins on the interval and sorts the output from the random number generator into them?

```
int main(){
#define NRAND 20000

int i, j;
double X, fX, Y, bin[200][100];

double Xdrand = (double) random()/(double) RAND_MAX;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("exp_rand.dat", "w+");

for (i = 0; i <= NRAND; i++)  //creates NRAND random values
{
    if (Xdrand != 1)          //ensures value is not 1, scales random value to interval
    {
        Xdrand = (double)random() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        X = Xdrand * 4;
        Y = Xdrand * 2;
        fX = 1/(exp(X));

        if (Y <= fX)
        {
            X = Y;
            return;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Aside: note that `for (i=0; i<=NRAND; i++)` actually creates *`NRAND+1`* random values.

Comment: What's is `random`? I know about `rand`

Comment: If you want to ensure that `Xdrand < 1` the you can divide by `(RAND_MAX + 1)` instead of by `RAND_MAX`, then you don't encounter the problem of skipping the functionality of any loop iteration.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you really should check if  `fopen` returns `NULL` and abort your program if yes.

Comment: You need an array `int count[200] = {0};` to store the current count for each bin.

Comment: How exactly do you want to sort and distribute the values into the bins? Could edit your question and add a small example with some values and where these values should be put ?

Comment: Michael Walz, I'd like to sort by order. So the first bin would contain all the values from 0 to (4/200), the next from (4/200) to (8/200), and so on across the entire interval.